# Polygon with n sides

Tags: geometry

I'm wondering if this is true:
If a polygon with n sides whose vertices are points of integer coordinates and the sides are equal, then n is even.
can you prove or disprove it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as the polygon is not required to be regular.  In particular the hexagon $(0,0),(5,0),(8,4),(5,8),(0,8),(-3,4)$ meets the requirement (and has an even number of sides)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very nice question. The answer to it is given by the paper

D.G. Ball, "Constructability of regular and equilateral polygons on square pinboards", Mathematical Gazette 57 (1973) p. 119-122.

Theorem. There exists an equilateral lattice $n$-gon in the plane if and only if $n$ is even. Furthermore, if $n$ is even, this polygon can be taken to be convex.

You can find a proof and much more [here](http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/lattice-points/5regular.html#anchor2).

Note: A planar polygon is called a lattice polygon if its vertices belong to the usual square lattice on the plane.